Cannot find name 'Dispatch'.ts(2304) and 'SetStateAction'.ts(2304)
I'm trying to pass my setState function to a child component, but when I pass it down, I get two typescript errors: Cannot find name 'Dispatch'.ts(2304) and Cannot find name 'SetStateAction'.ts(2304)
Does anyone know how to fix this?
// page.tsx
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Page() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

  return (
    <JobMenubar jobs={jobs} setJobs={setJobs} />
  )
}

// JobMenubar.tsx

type Props = {
  jobs: string[]
  setJobs: Dispatch<SetStateAction<never[]>> // Cannot find name 'Dispatch'.ts(2304) and Cannot find name 'SetStateAction'.ts(2304)
}

export default function JobMenubar({ filteredJobs, setFilteredJobs } : Props) {
  return (
    // ...
  )
}


I use Dispatch from my provider.
export type ObjectSend = {
    idDocumento: Guid;
    Url: string;
    Name: string;
};

import {
SetStateAction,
Dispatch } from "react";

setChecked: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ObjectSend[]>>;

